# Orchard - access a content type through different URLs so they use different views

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to create a CSS documentation library in Orchard. I want to save a description, CSS snippet and HTML snippet against each content type. The first view would show the description and CSS and HTML code written out. The second view would show a preview of what the CSS and HTML look like rendered.

```
cssdocumentation.com/content/item1
cssdocumentation.com/content/item1/live-preview
```

I've created the content type and the first view. But I'm not sure how to create the second view. I can see if I can create the alternative URL I can use the Url Alternates module to create an overriding .cshtml

To create an alternative URL I've looked at the autoroute module but this only allows you to adapt a single URL (unless I'm missing something?) and I've looked at Alias UI but this forces me to manually create an alternative URL everytime I create a content item.

Is this possible in Orchard without writting too much C#? (I'm a frontend developer so I only dabble in the behind the scenes stuff)

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think that the best approach is to write a Controller. But you would need a Module, to do this the code should be simple. To start investigate how to : use codegen to create a new Module, add a Controller and a Route

Comment: Gulp - I was hoping to avoid any C#, I haven't looked at the codegen tool either. I guess I've got some reading to do. Can anyone recommend examples/tutorials for creating modules that access content?

Comment: http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1 - this tutorial helped me hugely when creating my first module! If you take the time to carefully follow each step you'll finish part 11 with an abundance of module knowledge. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to do this within your own module. But as a secondary option instead of having a second page, combine this content with your first page and hide it with CSS. When the user clicks a button to navigate to the next step render the CSS/HTML result on the same page. You can do this in many ways, here are a few ideas:

1. Render the CSS/HTML result out straight away on the same page but hide it. Show it when the user clicks a button
2. using jQuery to render the result on the client side. More dynamic if you allow editing of the HTML and CSS.
3. Redirecting the user to the same page with specific url parameters which you can pick up in your alternate to modify the output.

Comment: I'd want to combine the CSS snippet with the core CSS of the site I'm documenting. Even if I didn't want the core CSS and injected just the CSS snippet using JavaScript the result would still be affected by Orchard's CSS.

Ideally I would be able to access just the CSS and HTML snippet through another route and render them in an iFrame.